# Getting asdf to load all files in a directory

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

Is there a way I can make asdf load all files (*.lisp) in a directory without naming them all in my .asd file? Using wildcards in both directory or filename spec doesn't work. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3):

See [`DIRECTORY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dir.htm):

```
 CL-USER> (directory "*.lisp")
 => ("a.lisp"
     "b.lisp"
     ...)
```

Then, call [`LOAD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_load.htm) for each file.

But then, you could also do:

```
CL-USER> (loop for f in * collect `(:file ,(pathname-name f)))
((:file "a") (:file "b"))
```

Then, you can copy that in your .asd file, so that your dependencies are a little more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the “package inferred system” extension of ASDF: https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf/The-package_002dinferred_002dsystem-extension.html#The-package_002dinferred_002dsystem-extension. You will have to adhere to a directory and file naming convention for this, but it is (superficially) a bit closer to how such things are organized in other languages.

I have to admit that I prefer the explicit layout in the asd file, though, because it keeps the concepts of systems, packages, and files clearly apart.

Answer (score 1):

The asdf repository comes with a asdf/contrib/wild-modules.lisp extension that does what you say. I'd still use package-inferred-system instead.